# Replicação Base de Dados MySQL

Tags: mysql, aplicação-web

Estou esboçando um projeto online e preciso de tirar uma dúvida referente a criação do banco de dados.

Terei um banco de dados EMPRESAS contendo a referência com nome e um código.

A partir deste banco EMPRESAS vou querer gerar uma estrutura nova do banco de dados, mas não vou querer ter que criar manualmente toda vez que cadastrar uma nova empresa fazer a criação do banco na unha, existe uma função que posso fazer para replicar esta estrutura ao cadastrar uma nova empresa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o dump default desse banco alterando o nome do banco para uma slug da empresa nova.

Aonde assim que cadastrada sera upado esse dump no mysql.

ps.: Não sei se ficou prático a explicação mas posso tentar melhorar um pouco caso necessario

Comment: Mas eu conseguiria fazer o upload do dump ao realizar um cadastro na tabela EMPRESA? Somente usando o gerenciador do banco de dados MySQL.

Comment: Interessante mas existe algum requisito para que se possa dar um CREATE DATABASE de fora pra dentro porque eu nunca tentei isso, crio todos os bancos através do gerenciador de banco de dados ou phpmyadmin.

Comment: você simplesmente separa um dump default e quando efetua o cadastro pela aplicação você abre esse dump pela aplicação trocando o create database pelo nome que quiser e realiza o import. No cadastro direto no cadastro, você pode utilizar uma trigger ou store procedure para isto.